# C++ Average Calculation Function Returning 0

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that calculates the batting averages of a user defined number of players. The program displays the name of a player, their number of times at bat, number of hits, and their batting average. Finally, it displays the total number of times the players were at bat, the total number of hits, and the overall average. For some reason, the functions that calculate the individual player average and overall average are returning 0. It's probably something small, but I'm stumped as to how to try and fix it.

```
//Batting Average Calculator

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//Create Structure
struct Record
{
    string name;
    int AB;
    int hit;
    double avg;
};


int getSize(int);
void getData(Record[], int );
int calculateTotalAB(Record[], int, int);
int calculateTotalHit(Record[], int, int);
double calculateTotalAvg(Record[], int, double);
void calculateAvg(Record[], int);
void display(Record[], int, int , int, double);


int main()
{
    const int MaxSize = 50;
    Record players[MaxSize]; 

    int size = 0;
    int totalAB = 0;
    int totalHit = 0;
    double totalAvg = 0;

    size = getSize(size);
    getData(players, size);
    totalAB = calculateTotalAB(players, size, totalAB);
    totalHit = calculateTotalHit(players, size, totalHit);
    calculateAvg(players,size);
    totalAvg = calculateTotalAvg(players, size, totalAvg);
    display(players, size, totalHit, totalAB, totalAvg);
}

//get number of players to be calculated
int getSize(int size)
{
    cout << "Please enter the number of players on the team: ";
    cin >> size;
    return size;
}

//get Player name, AB, and hit
void getData(Record players[], int size)
{
    string dummy;
    getline(cin, dummy);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please input the name of student " << i + 1 << ": ";
        getline(cin, players[i].name);
        cout << "Please input the number of times "<<  players[i].name << " was at bat:  ";
        cin >> players[i].AB;
        cout << "Please input the number of hits for " << players[i].name << ": ";
        cin >> players[i].hit;
        cout << " " << endl;
        getline(cin, dummy);
    }
}

int calculateTotalAB(Record players[], int size, int totalAB)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        totalAB = totalAB + players[i].AB;
    }
    return totalAB;
}

int calculateTotalHit(Record players[], int size, int totalHit)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        totalHit = totalHit + players[i].hit;
    }
    return totalHit;
}

void calculateAvg(Record players[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        players[i].avg = players[i].hit / players[i].AB;
    }
}

double calculateTotalAvg(Record players[], int size, double totalAvg)
{
    double j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        j = j + players[i].avg;
    }
    totalAvg = j / size;
    return totalAvg;
}

void display(Record players[], int size, int totalHit, int totalAB, double totalAvg)
{
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(3);
    cout << "Player        AB         Hit         Avg" << endl;
    cout << "  " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << players[i].name << setw(8) << players[i].AB << setw(5) << players[i].hit << setw(5) << players[i].avg;
    }
    cout << "  " << endl;
    cout << "Totals      " << totalAB << "      " << totalHit << "      " << totalAvg << endl;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: try to divide 1 by 3 using only integer numbers on paper and you will see what is the problem. btw did you really write all this code without testing pieces of it ?

Comment: No I didn't, I'm still pretty new to C++. What is the best way to test functions as i'm writing them? Should I just make separate projects consisting of the functions and use dummy values to test them? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are dividing an `int` by an `int`, which is calculated as an `int`, and storing it in a `double`. What you have to do is explicitly cast at least one of your `int` values to a double first, like this:

```
void calculateAvg(Record players[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        players[i].avg = players[i].hit / (double) players[i].AB;
    }
}
```